# Sequelize - Enable paranoid: true on query level while its false on the defined Model

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

So lets say I have a Sequelize model defined with paranoid defaulting to "false":

```
const Country = sequelize.define('Country', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    code: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    currency: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    languages: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    deletedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  });
```

Now when I invoke `Model.destroy()` on any records of Country table, the records would be hard deleted. Enabling `paranoid: true` on the Model definition would result in soft deletes.

I wanted to achieve the opposite of this. Where, the paranoid flag on model definition is set to false and we need to explicitly define a flag on the `Model.destroy()` method to soft-delete an entry and by default all records would be hard deleted.

I tried to sift through the documentation in order to find something but couldn't. Would appreciate any help I can get in case I missed something or if there's a workaround.

**Why I need to do this? Some background**

I joined a project with about 100+ defined models (even more) on which the paranoid flag is not defined and is false by default. Thankfully, the createdAt, updatedAt and deletedAt timestamps are defined explicitly. But any call to the `Model.destroy()` function results in a hard delete.

I need to introduce the functionality of a soft delete without changing any model definitions (because that would result in unintended consequences). Again, thankfully, the Model.destroy() method is wrapped in a function which is used in the entire codebase.

I was thinking of introducing an optional flag on this wrapper function which would indicate whether the delete needs to be soft or hard. So the default functionality would be hard delete unless explicitly specified to be a soft delete.

**Worst case solution I can think of is** that in case soft delete is required, then replace the destroy method with a raw query where I update the deletedAt timestamp manually. But hoping to find cleaner solutions than this :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to use `force: false` option in case of soft-delete and `force: true` in case of hard-delete:

```js
async function wrappedDestroy(item, isSoftDelete) {
   await item.destroy({ force: !isSoftDelete })
}
```

Of course, you need to turn on `paranoid: true` in the model because it also affects all `findAll/findOne` queries as well (I suppose you wish to hide all soft-deleted records from `findAll/findOne` by default).

Comment: Interesting. Didn't think of it like this. Good idea! But this also means that I'll have to go set paranoid: true on the 100+ models now. The lazy guy inside me isn't the happiest right now. :D

Comment: But the bright side is that action is one-time thing! So be cheerful!